# How to set probability of something happens based on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder how to set probability of something happens based on a variable.
Let's say:

```js
var a = "5235235";
var b = "5235235";
var rand = Math.random();
if (rand < 0.3) {
  console.log("30% chance");
} else {
  console.log("70% chance");
}
```

I have tried the percentage chances like so, but I don't really know how to set for example 70% chance of something happened if variable a is equal to variable b. Any ideas?

Comment: Percentage change or percentage chance?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you're checking equality of variables, you don't control the probability, the variables just have what they have. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: >_< If a == b set 70% chance of console.log for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to hold the percentage, instead of hard-coding it, then assign it depending on the condition.

```
var pct = 0.3;
if (a == b) {
    pct = 0.7;
}
var rand = Math.random();
if (rand < pct) {
    console.log("Success!");
} else {
    console.log("Failure. :(");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

okay so if you want two mutually exclusive events with one occurring 30% of the time and the other occurring 70% of the time, then

```
chance = random.randint(1,100)
if chance <= 30:
print "30% chance of getting this"
elif chance <= 70:
print "70% change of getting this"
```